# How to clear a known password in AMI BIOS?

Tags: bios, passwords

I have just got a tiny no-brand MicroPC and foolishly set an Administrator password in its AMI BIOS. I DO KNOW the password, but still want to get rid of it.

Typically, when one wants to clear a BIOS password it is enough to just change it to blank, but not in this BIOS. If I just press enter for a new password when changing it, I get a message "Invalid Password". I can change it to anything else, but not clear. BIOS does not have a dedicated option to clear the password either.

Is there some trick to it?

I did an extensive search for an answer before posting the question here. Almost all results are about removing an UNKNOWN password and involve taking a CMOS battery out or switching jumpers on the motherboard. Since I DO KNOW the password it seems there should be away to clear it without going that far.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/ami-bios-password-removal/. If not, searching for `ami bios clear password` gives quite a few results.

Comment: Yes, I did an extensive search for an answer before posting the question here. Almost all results are about removing an UNKNOWN password and involve taking a CMOS battery out or switching jumpers on the motherboard. Since I DO KNOW the password it seems there should be away to clear it without going that far.

Comment: As described in the [question guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) _"Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers"_. It's a good idea to check the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour), Asking and Answering in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) and some older questions with [accepted answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn how SE sites work.